# Установка Perl модулей в Denwer

Tags: perl

Здравствуйте. Я начал изучать Perl. Для этого скачал и установил на Denwer дополнение ActivePerl. Недавно понадобилось установить на него модуль (HTML Template). Погуглил, нашел команды для командной строки:

```
ppm install HTML-Template
```

Ввел их в командную строку Windows, как было сказано на том сайте. Итог:

> "ppm" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом

Что делать? Как теперь жить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо прописать полный путь до ppm, что-то типа C:\perl\bin\ppm.exe install HTML-Template или прописать директорию в которой находится ppm в "Переменные среды"